# How to fail/stop build when executing local powershell script on remote server via msbuild

Tags: msbuild

I have read dozens of posts about failing the build various ways, but they are all either not quite what I'm trying to do or simply haven't worked for me.

From what I've read, I believe there's a bug with powershell when using the -FilePath option, but I don't know how else to run my script remotely.

This is my test Target:

```
  <Target Name="TestPS" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <PowerShellExe Condition=" '$(PowerShellExe)'=='' ">%WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe</PowerShellExe>
      <ScriptFile Condition=" '$(ScriptFile)'=='' ">$(SolutionDir)WebApplication99\Testing.ps1</ScriptFile>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="Running powershell script..." Importance="high"/>
    <Exec Command="$(PowerShellExe) -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted -command &quot;&amp; { Invoke-Command -ComputerName myserver -FilePath &apos;$(ScriptFile)&apos; -Args &apos;$(Configuration)&apos; } &quot;"/>
  </Target>
```

And this is Testing.ps1:

```
param([String]$environment)

# this doesn't seem to help, but added anyway.. 
trap { $_.Exception.Message; exit 1; continue }

#stop on errors..  
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

#type-o to fail:
xWrite-Host("Backing up files...")
```

I've tried adding ; exit $lastexitcode to the end of Testing.ps1 as well as to the end of my Exec Command.  I tried adding the trap{} to Testing.ps1 as you can see.  I've seen other posts about just having an Exec Command with $(PowerShellExe) SomeScript.ps1, only to have code in SomeScript.ps1 actually Invoke-Command and run Testing.ps1 - but that seems strange... do you really have to have two ps1 files??  As well as various other combinations referenced.

Surely there's an easier way to execute a local ps1 script file on a remote server (do note I need to pass it an argument), and if that script encounters an error - return something so msbuild knows to stop?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks-

Comment: you could try if(...) { exit 1} as any error number above 0 will be an error.